# What is the proper location to place jQuery and or jQuery plugin in a Drupal installation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I just want it to be at a standard place. Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery 1.2.6 is already included in Drupal, so you don't need to add that yourself. If you need a newer version of jQuery, I recommend [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

To maintain jQuery plugins, you can indeed put them in a folder you like (I would choose sites/all/libraries) or you can consider the [jQuery plugin](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_plugin) module.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a single place to put it, but common ones are:

- Inside a folder in your custom module.
- `sites/all/libraries`
- In your theme's js folder